# Multi Concurrent In-flight Request Deduplication

Tags: go, optimization, concurrency, system-design

Can you help me? Let say we have:

- A service `S` that when you give an array of number `x`, it will give back an item detail for each id inside array `x`. Assume this is an expensive call.

Now, you have a lot of request that come at the same time. If for each request brings an id, we can handle it with [singleflight](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) like the following code:

```
var group singleflight.Group

func GetResult(id int64) (itemDetail, error) {
    key := fmt.Sprintf("Key%d",id) // key for identifier the same request id
    result, err, _ := group.Do(key, func() (inteface{}, error) {
        result, err := GetFromService(id) // Get data from the service S
        if err!= nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return result, nil
    }
    return result, err
}
```

Now, what if for each request, there is an array of ids. Is there any way to handle all of the requests such that each id in `x` will only queried to service `S` once and the other duplicate ids will wait from something (if possible) to get the result?

For example, there are 3 concurrent in-flight request. The 1st request ids are `1,2,3`, the 2nd request ids are `1,2,4`, and the 3rd request ids are `1,3,4`. The target is to only call the service `S` 2 times. The 1st call will request for ids `1,2,3`. After this call is over, it can share the result to the 2nd and 3rd request and consequently, the 1st request is finished.

While the 1st call is still calling to the Service S, the 2nd request came and from there we know that this 2nd request only need to request for id 4, and thus subsequently do that (because the 1st call when finish will "share" the result to this 2nd call).

While the 1st call and 2nd call is in-flight, let's assume that the 3rd call came, and we know for sure that in the 3rd call.. it doesn't need to do anything other than waiting for the 1st request and 2nd request to finish. and after the 1st request and 2nd request finish, they will subsequently share their call result from `X` and ending the 3rd request

I seem to can't find any question related to this on so after checking on so many threads... If this is a well known questions, and already have the answers... please help and provide the solution.

If there's any library that specifically does this thing (and operate in singleflight manner), that would be really help.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly stops you from looking up and storing several ids in the cache? You seem to know how to cache stuff, so just do it.

Comment: @Volker this question is not related to cache per-se.